# Computing connections on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\nabla$ denote the Levi-Civita connection on the following manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Riemannian metric $g$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}^3=\lbrace (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid z>0 \rbrace
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
g=\frac{(dx)^2+(dy)^2+(dz)^2}{z^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A= z\partial_x \, , \, B=z\partial_y \, , \, C= z\partial_z
\end{equation}

I want to compute $\nabla_X Y$ for all $X,Y \in \lbrace A,B,C \rbrace$. I know that it should be easiest to do this via Koszul's formula, but I don't know exactly how to use it. Koszul's formula reads as on wikipedia:

\begin{equation}
2g(\nabla_X Y, Z)=\partial_X(g(Y,Z))+\partial_Y(g(X,Z))-\partial_Z(g(X,Y))+g([X,Y],Z)-g([X,Z],Y)-g([Y,Z],X)
\end{equation}

I don't know exactly how to interpret this formula. First, what is $Z$? is it a dummy variable in this case or what? and second, what does the term $\partial_X$ and the others mean? Since it seems that I need to take derivatives with respect to derivatives? All the other terms I know how to handle, but the others mentioned are really bugging me.

Okay, if I try to let $X=A$ and $Y=B$, then the first term in Koszul's formula is 
$$g(Y,Z)=\frac{dx(B)dx(Z)+dy(B)dy(Z)+dz(B)dz(Z)}{z^2}= \frac{dx(z\partial_y)dx(Z)+dy(z\partial_y)dy(Z)+dz(z\partial_y)dz(Z)}{z^2}=\frac{zdx(\partial_y)dx(Z)+zdy(\partial_y)dy(Z)+zdz(\partial_y)dz(Z)}{z^2}=\frac{z \cdot 0 \cdot dx(Z)+z \cdot 1 \cdot dy(Z)+z \cdot 0 \cdot dz(Z)}{z^2}=\frac{z\cdot 1 \cdot dy(Z)}{z^2}$$

Or am I totally off track here?

Comment: Yes, $Z$ is just a placeholder index. Here $\partial_U f$ just means the action of the vector field $U$ on the function $f$, $U \cdot f = df(U)$. Finally, you can just compute the derivatives $\nabla_{\partial_x} \partial_y$, etc., which has the advantage that the Lie bracket terms disappear (when one takes $Z$ to be a coordinate vector field) and then just use the Leibniz Rule.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Where exactly does the derivative $\nabla_{\partial_x}\partial_y$ come from? How exactly is the notion of an action used here? Something like for example $\partial_X(g(Y,Z))=X \cdot g(Y,Z)=dg(X)$?

Comment: Koszul's Formula tells you exactly how to compute it, just substitute $X = \partial_x$ and $Y = \partial_y$.

Comment: To use the formula you have to calculate some Lie bracket, I have the feeling that finding the Christoffel symbols will be easier.

Comment: I have computed the Lie brackets $[X,Y]$ for all $A,B,C$, so that should not be the problem.